# home page displaying incorrectly on chrome & ie; fine on safari & firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, html, cross-browser

The landing page for my site, http://www.warrenhowden.com, is only displaying the bottom half of the page on IE and Chrome. Safari & FF seem to load it fine. Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Warren Howden - Music</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="warrenhowden.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body id="page-home" style="width:99%; background-color:black; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: -1px 0 0.2em blue, 0 1px 0.2em blue, 1px 0 0.2em blue, 0 -1px 0.2em red; border:0; margin-bottom:0; padding:0;">
<div style="position:absolute;">
<img src="images/landingpage.jpg" alt="Welcome to Warren Howden's Music" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%; z-index:-1; border:0;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"/>
<a style="position:absolute; top:12%; left:18%;" href="read.php" title="life &amp; influences">READ</a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:12%; left:47%;" href="look.php" title="pictures">LOOK</a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:12%; left:74%;" href="listen.php" title="tunes">LISTEN</a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:47%; left:17%;" href="watch.php" title="video clips">WATCH</a>
<a style="position:absolute; left:40%; width:20%;" id="centretext" href="#"><span style="font-family:'Alice', serif;">WARREN&nbsp;HOWDEN<br />
</span><span style="font-family:'FrancoisOne', sans-serif; font-size:1.3em; letter-spacing:4px; text-decoration:overline; padding-left:3px;">FLUTEBOXING</span></a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:47%; left:76%;" href="see.php" title="catch Warren live">SEE</a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:84%; left:14%;" href="soundtracks.php" title="other projects">SOUNDTRACKS</a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:84%; left:47%;" href="links.php" title="cool stuff">LINKS</a>
<a style="position:absolute; top:84%; left:73%;" href="contact.php" title="email, newsletter">CONTACT</a>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably the absolute positioning. Can't you just do this in 3 rows across split into three columns to keep everything nice and tidy?

Comment: there's so many problems in your code, 1.try removing all the inline styles and define in css. 2.don't use behavior: url(csshover.htc) as that affects performance especially when you have so many href attributes in your page. 3. #page-home {margin-top:-25%} this is where your problem is, rearrange your @media query order from smallest screen size to largest, and start with default one.

Comment: off topic: why are you using xhtml strict doctype?Any reason you can't use the html5 doctype? Do you actally need the strict xhtml rules? Nobody is seriously recommending xhtml for anything today.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that in the css of `body#page-home` there is an attribute `margin-bottom:0;`. You need to change that to `margin:auto;`. That's all, it will work fine on Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

add this css rule

```
body{
margin:0
}
```

all browser have default margin and padding, when you want use css you should be write or use css reset - example:

```
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:none;
}
```

or you can download existing css reset file.